# How to wrap y axis labels with pygal

Tags: python, pygal

I am trying to wrap long y axis labels on my plot with pygal.
My current method which worked with matplotlib:

```
labels = ['\n'.join(wrap(l, 20)) for l in labels]
```

The newline characters seem to be rendered as whitespaces..
How can I fix this?